# Does an Azure.Authentication.ApplicationTokenProvider have an expiry for a ServiceClientCredentials?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, authentication

The following code retrieves a `ServiceClientCredentials` instance against an Azure account/subscription:

```
var credentials = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(_tenantId, _clientId, _clientSecret);
```

Is there any way of knowing how long these credentials are valid before they expire? Do they expire?

Basically, I was looking at some code and it was calling this method every single time it was about to do some stuff against their Azure account/subscription. So I was wondering: why not just remember this instance for a bit (in memory ... not perm in a DB, etc) and keep reusing it while it's 'valid'.

Is this possible?

Comment: Service credentials do expire. I believe now the max lifespan of a service credential is 2 years.

Comment: which means it's pretty safe to reuse a credential. eg. store it in a private variable, in a class instance (think, singleton)

Comment: I would say yes.